# How to send NACK to Solace queue from Solace listener using JMS API?

Tags: java, jms, solace, retry-logic

Need your help to find the solution. Current implementation details:

```java
SolConnectionFactory connectionFactory = SolJmsUtility.createConnectionFactory(); // for create connection factory using host , vpn,trust store,keystore with auth scheme AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE
this.connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(); // connection creation
session = connection.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE); // session creation using client acknowledge
```

Using MessageListener to listen the queue

```java
public class MyListener implements MessageListener 

    public void onMessage(Message message) // receive the message and process
    { 
        /* in this method validating the message (poison message) 
         * and publish to kafka, once receive the success message
         * from kafka acknowledge the message
         */
        message.acknowledge();
    }
```

Problem : If Kafka broker went down how to do retry? We had a discussion with internal Solace team.

**We assume** that if client is not calling the `message.acknowledge()` Solace will do  the retry but internal Solace team clarified that it is using windowing mechanism, so if subsequent message is acknowledge then previous message will also acknowledged and deleted.

**Their suggestion** is to send back the NACK (negative acknowledgment) for failed message then Solace can do retry that message. How to send the NACK using Java API?

What are the suggested value for `Max_Un_Ack_Message` and `Max_Redeliver_Count`?

Maven Dependency for Solace:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.solacesystems</groupId>
    <artifactId>sol-jms</artifactId>
    <version>10.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the JMS API and you want to trigger a redelivery then you have a couple of options.

You can use a [transacted session](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Connection.html#createSession-boolean-int-). When processing a message is successful you acknowledge the message and `commit()` the `javax.jms.Session`. When processing is unsuccessful you call `rollback()` on the `javax.jms.Session`.

Alternatively, you can use [`javax.jms.Session.recover()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Session.html#recover--). Here's what the JavaDoc says:

> Stops message delivery in this session, and restarts message delivery with the oldest unacknowledged message.
>
> All consumers deliver messages in a serial order. Acknowledging a received message automatically acknowledges all messages that have been delivered to the client.
>
> Restarting a session causes it to take the following actions:
>
> - Stop message delivery
> - Mark all messages that might have been delivered but not acknowledged as "redelivered"
> - Restart the delivery sequence including all unacknowledged messages that had been previously delivered. Redelivered messages do not have to be delivered in exactly their original delivery order.

This, of course, assumes that the Solace JMS client actually implements the specified behavior here.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.                                                                                                               I am using **connection.session.recover();** --> for downstream failure in solace consumer
It keeps retry the message which is unable to process.
Is this recover() method is good to use for production scenario?(running multiple consumer instances)
Is any bottleneck to use this method?

The retry message don't have the property to claim that is retry message.(retry count or redelivery count).

Answer (score 0):

As per the discussion [here](https://solace.community/discussion/1010/how-to-send-nack-negative-acknowledgement-using-java-api), `message.acknowledge()` is unrelated to windowing. Since you are using an asynchronous solution in your example, if you dont call `stop()`the transport window will close and the message will not be acknowledged.

`message.acknowledge()` is only for acknowledging the message has been received and consumed where the message is already removed from the persistent storage on the Solace broker. Note that unacknowledged messages are only redelivered on the next consumer to connect.